# Using log4net RemoteSyslogAppender with .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, log4net

I am trying to use both a RollingFileAppender and RemoteSyslogAppender in a .Net Core app with log4net 2.0.8. Here's what my log4net.config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <root>
    <priority value="Debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="SyslogAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="C:\ProgressiveLogs\ProgLoggerNetCoreDemo.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="14" />
    <maximumFileSize value="15000KB" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="SyslogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RemoteSyslogAppender">
    <remoteAddress name="Address" value="syslogServer" />
    <remotePort name="Port" value="514" />
    <layout type="ProgressiveLogging.Core.ProgLayout.ProgPatternLayout, ProgressiveLogging.Core">
      <conversionPattern value="%json%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

As you can see, I'm using a custom pattern for the syslog appender. When I run my .Net Core version of the app (which uses a .Net Standard 1.3 build of ProgressiveLogging.Core), I do get output to the RollingFileAppender file, but not the RemoteSyslogAppender.  When I run my my test app using .Net 4.6.2 (using a .Net 4.0 build of ProgressiveLogging.Core) it outputs fine to both appenders.

I have found documentation online stating that the log4net RemoteSysLogAppender is supported for .Net Standard 1.3 (https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html).

Has anyone else been able to get something similar to work (using RemoteSysLogAppender with .Net Core or .Net Standard)?

Added 2017-09-01: I have done further investigation and find that this boils down to a major difference in how UDP packets are built and sent between .Net 4.* and .Net Standard. .Net 40, which works, sends the UDP message all in one datagram (packet), whereas .Net Standard splits the message up into a bunch of packets, which packets appear to be delimited by the commas in our JSON message. Apparently, our syslog daemon can't understand such nonsense. I'm going to do some direct testing to see if I can make a difference in what gets sent via UDP to syslog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much more thorough investigation I have found that there is not a problem with log4net RemoteSyslogAppender. My problem was that I was formatting the JSON message that ultimately was sent by the System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient. The formatting added CRLFs to the string, which then the UdpClient delimited the message and fragmented on those CRLF boundaries. That was making no sense to Syslog. It was a very simple fix - remove the formatting options from the call to NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject. I had copied a snippet from somewhere that included formatting of the Json string. Works perfect now!